# PHP - Display 4 most recent images from directory

Tags: php

Very new to PHP. I have sucessfully got this piece of code working to display 4 images from a directory, however it shows the **first** 4 images by name (001.png, 002.png, 003.png and 004.png) which are the lowest numbers and happen to be the least recently uploaded:

```
<?php
$pictures = glob("directory/*.png"); 
for( $i=0; $i<=3; $i++ ){ 
echo "<img src=\"".$pictures[$i]."\" />"; 
}  
?>
```

I am looking to change that to get the 4 most recently uploaded in a directory by name.
In other words, I would like to display the **last** 4 images with the highest number.
I have tried this below however I am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE on line 4

```
<?php
$pictures = glob("directory/*.png"); 
$no_pictures = count($pictures)-1 
$limit = $no_pictures-3 
for( $i = $no_pictures; $i >= $limit; $i--; ){ 
echo "<img src=\"".$pictures[$i]."\" />\n"; 
}  
?>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Also i'am new at PHP. How can you assing $pictures var to glob("directory/*.png"); ? maybe there are more than one picture in directory. is not an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the ending semicolons `;` on lines 3 & 4 [edit] AND you have an extra one in your `for` loop after `$i--` -

```
<?php
$pictures = glob("directory/*.png"); 
$no_pictures = count($pictures)-1;  // was missing ;
$limit = $no_pictures-3;            // was missing ;
for( $i = $no_pictures; $i >= $limit; $i--){  // removed ; after $i--
echo "<img src=\"".$pictures[$i]."\" />\n"; 
}  
?>
```

Comment: Great. I also had to remove the semicolon on line 5 after $i--
and it worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: See my edit. I realized after posting, that you also had a extra `;` after `$i--`.